# semi-space copy allocation failed, javascript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript

I was wondering why the below code returns a memory allocation error?

```
var countValidWords = function(sentence) {
    let words = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < sentence.length; ++i){
        let word = '';
        while(sentence[i] !== ' '){
            word += sentence[i];
            ++i;
        }
        if(word !== '')
            words.push(word);
    }
    console.log(words);
};
```

I'm simply trying to build an array of words from the inputted sentence (words can be separated by more than one space).

Comment: Provide [mcve].

Comment: the `while` loop is never ending.

Comment: If the sentence doesn't end with a space, you'll go into an infinite loop looking for the space after the last word.

Answer (score 1):

If the sentence doesn't end with a space, the `while` loop never ends, because it doesn't check if it has gone past the end of the string. As a result, you go into an infinite loop appending `undefined` to `word`, until you run out of memory.

Add a check that `i` is within the string length there.

```js
var countValidWords = function(sentence) {
    let words = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < sentence.length; ++i){
        let word = '';
        while(i < sentence.length && sentence[i] !== ' '){
            word += sentence[i];
            ++i;
        }
        if(word !== '')
            words.push(word);
    }
    console.log(words);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The while clause needs to check for `i` getting out of bounds:

```
while(i < sentence.length && sentence[i] !== ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this? It's not the most optimized version you might find but it works.
You had an infinite loop on the while.

```
var countValidWords = function(sentence) {
    let words = [];
    let word = ''
    for(let i = 0; i < sentence.length; ++i){
        if(sentence[i] != '' && sentence[i] != ' '){
          word += sentence[i];
        }
        if(sentence[i] == ' ' || sentence[i + 1] === undefined){
          words.push(word);
          word = '';
        }
    }
    console.log(words);
};
```